# Any IDea what would cause a ReentrantLock to deadlock OrientDB?

Tags: deadlock, orientdb

My Java app is hanging regularly, and the place that it stops is shown in the attached screenshot.

Context: using a Json data document, I:
 - Insert/Update a vertex using the document
 - Iterate know relationships
 - For each relationship, create an edge from current vertex to related vertex
 - Create an entry in a logging document to track what is happening

The deadlock usually occurs near the bottom of the flow. Here is the image.

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Patrick

Comment: Once a record is deadlocked, any attempts to access it produce the following error in the logs:  `2015-03-30 16:31:39:197 SEVERE Internal server error:
com.orientechnologies.common.concur.OTimeoutException: Can not lock record for 2000 ms. seems record is deadlocked by other record [ONetworkProtocolHttpDb]`

Comment: It doesn't mean it's a deadlock, but maybe the command took too much time to complete. Try to enlarge timeouts with this setting on client: -Dstorage.record.lockTimeout=10000. It's 2000 by default.

Comment: Unfortunately, I let it wait for over 20 minutes before killing it. It just sits there at Unsafe.park(). My hunch is that the commit of the base record does not complete/finalize before the call begins that creates an outbound edge on that vertex, thus creating the condition. All of the calls I'm using are supposed to be synchronous, though when I do inside a transaction, the calls all batch up until the graph.commit() is called, at which point I don't have visibility into the way the operations get executed under the covers. Hopefully the order of operations within the txis strictly enforced.